# nvidia - high power consumption on idle GTX 1080 cards

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I observe that my 4 Nvidia GTX cards consume ~180W, even when no process is using them. 
Could anyone of you tell if there is any way to reduce it, please?

System: Linux Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Mon Oct  8 17:20:23 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  On   | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8    28W / 160W |      1MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 107...  On   | 00000000:0B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   53C    P0    33W / 105W |      1MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 108...  On   | 00000000:0C:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   56C    P0    62W / 125W |      1MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 108...  On   | 00000000:0D:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   55C    P0    61W / 125W |      1MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved this problem. It turned out that my card were running in P0 (performance mode). The following command changes performance mode to P8:

```
$ nvidia-settings --ctrl-display :0 -a "[gpu:0]/GPUPowerMizerMode=2"
```