# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS locks up in shutdown (UEFI)

Tags: shutdown, lenovo, freeze, reboot, 20.04

If I shutdown my Laptop (Lenovo ideapad 100) it freezes and won't shut down. I also have this problem in other distros like Deepin or Debian.

I've take me some time and googled about it.

I have tried to edit the grub file and replaced "quiet splash" with "quiet splash acpi=force". Doesn't Work.

---

Results from command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`:

```
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /swapfile...
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-discord-109.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for discord, revision 109.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 116.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 24.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 27.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1506.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 433.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: snap-snapd-7264.mount: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 7264.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Apr 29 11:53:39 marcel-lenovo-ubuntu systemd-journald[316]: Journal stopped
```

I don't know what's wrong with that. It's just freezing and doesn't completely shut down

Outputs from

@nobody

```
    journalctl -b -1 -e
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/927f38a0-c962-47de-9361-f1730032704e.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: media-debian\x2dhome\x2dpartition.mount: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/debian-home-partition.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1ebf0f02\x2dcdd8\x2d44d9\x2d80f9\x2d7078de79e191.service: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/1ebf0f02-cdd8-44d9-80f9-7078de79e191.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: home.mount: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Unmounted /home.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3bbf1ad8\x2db0d0\x2d464e\x2da73b\x2d9337e16d95d0.service: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/3bbf1ad8-b0d0-464e-a73b-9337e16d95d0.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Mär 07 10:18:28 Guilmon systemd-journald[319]: Journal stopped
```

what @nobody try to fix it

- disable ondemand.service #in debian I have not such service
- add mds=full bootoption #because of `MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible`
- disable wake on lan #in uefi

Note my Sytems boot in bios mode (legacy only in uefi); my kernel is 5.4 kerneltree, not hw stack.

[nobody's dmesg](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sknCZbjcjs/)

Comment: Have you waited 40 minutes for it to shutdown, then rebooted and run `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` to see the logs at shutdown?

Comment: I will try and send you the results

Comment: If the issue continues on a different OS's then would the issue not be with Ubuntu/the os and with your computer?

Comment: @nobody This line `acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling ASPM` is present in your dmesg log. Please see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198969/how-to-find-acpi-drivers-for-specific-acpi-device-solving-kernel-suspend-bug/1200540#1200540)

Comment: @nobody As a workaround try adding the kernel parameters  `acpi_osi=!` and `acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\"`. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322717/968501) for mor information.

Comment: @Raffa i check bootparameter `pcie_aspm=force` first, and uefi menue for possible poweroptions.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a number of reasons for Ubuntu not to complete shutdown.
As examples:

1. [Encrypted swap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288915/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-does-not-shut-down#comment2189089_1288915).
2. [Bug #1464917](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917).
3. [CMOS corruption](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276356/226614).

There seem to be also a number of things you can try.
As examples:

1. [Waiting for 35 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288915/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-does-not-shut-down#comment2188204_1288915) after shutdown, in case a timeout of 30 minutes is in place. Then, execute `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` as you did (it is not clear if you did wait for the 35 minutes).

   *Post in the question the results*.
2. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/680223/226614) (no need to copy entirely here since it is in askubuntu)

   `sudo swapoff -a` prior to shutdown.

   *Post in the question the results*.
3. *Post in the question a screen capture* or photo of the point where the system freezes.
4. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/574210/226614) (no need to copy here since it is in askubuntu).
5. Check if [swap is encrypted](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2012/09/11/how-to-check-if-swap-is-encrypted-in-ubuntu/):

    If `swapon --summary` returns a description line for the swap, then it is encrypted, if it returns only the header line, then it is not.

    If `sudo blkid | grep swap` returns a description of the swap, then it is encrypted.

   *Post in the question the results*.
6. Using `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"` in grub ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/226614)).

   *Post in the question the results*.

Additional information would be useful for you to *Post*:

1. `uname -a`
2. What ways are you using to shutdown?

As per the output you show, and comparing to [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=317832), it appears that swap encryption may be the cause.
I will wait **until you post the extra info mentioned above** (see "Post..." above).

**Related**:

1. [ubuntu 20.04 desktop does not shut down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288915/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-does-not-shut-down)
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/isi3wx/shutdown_is_unable_to_power_off_system_in_ubuntu/
3. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=318330
4. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/17-10-shutdown-swap-issue/15458
5. https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/encrypted-swap-partition-on/

Comment: Thanks but this is not my question I will set my log level on debug and try to unmount my swap partition before shutdown

Comment: Then I do not understand what is your question...

Comment: I start bounty because I have similar problem I will try your efforts thanks

Comment: @nobody - Now I see that the poster of the original question is not the same as the bounty offerer (you). So the question may be similar, but not exactly the same.
I suggest you append the question (yes, it might be a little bit of a mix up) with the specific results you see from some commands as needed (`journalctl`, `dmesg`, etc.)
Clarify in the EDIT that it is you who is editing.
Otherwise, it would be difficult to help.

Comment: done, thanks for reading.

Comment: @nobody - Did you try solutions suggested here?

Comment: yes but I'm not every day online and to check I have always to reboot and make the notebook powerless.

Comment: @nobody - Great!

Answer (score 0):

I've changed DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s in /etc/systemd/system.conf after reading this https://medium.com/@sbyang/slow-shut-down-of-ubuntu-18-04-e5fcc31255e2. It helps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the governor.

And wost likely, you just need to configure requests to the kernel so that your device does not fall into a coma.
But you need to do it yourself, taking into account the density of the battery at a certain percentage of the battery charge and the load on the device's memory.

This is a call to the kernel in the background, the time of the call to the attempt to switch the core.
Configuring the algorithms for running background processes so that the device does not cross the red line.

`gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

```
vm.dirty_
vm.laptop_
kernel.sched_wakeup_
kernel.sched_migration_
```

And I'll tell you a secret, I don't have any grub at all and everything works fine in sleep mode.

That's just I don't fully understand how to prevent disconnecting the Internet in sleep mode, it turns off in any case, with a check mark in the settings, and without it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm have to apologize for my misleading bounty. In my case lubuntu does poweroff complete.

I compare which services run in groovy and in focal. then I remember I always deactivate systemd-timesyncd.service after fresh install.

It seems during distro-upgrade (from 19.10 to 20.04) It was enabled again.

I deactivate it again. Since then I have no problems with cold boots.

Sorry for taking your time in vain.

Nobody.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the Legacy boot process (BIOS rather than UEFI) setting on your Lenovo Ideapad?

Enter into the BIOS and search for a menu entry labeled Boot or Startup.

Choose the Legacy BIOS boot option instead of UEFI.

Save your changes before exiting.